# Do invokeAll and InvokeAny calls with timeouts specified override settings configured in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, singleton, threadpool, executorservice

Do calls to [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) and [invokeAny](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAny%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), with timeout length and unit specified in their call, on a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) configured with core, max, timeout, time unit, and bounded queue override the timeout settings of the executor when executing the tasks?  In the case of invokeAll, this would apply when using the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method on one of the returned futures (you can specify an additional timeout on the get).  In the case of invokeAny, it applies to the call itself.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(coreSize, maxSize, poolTO, tu, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize));
```

...and in the class that contains this threadPool object, I expose the submit, invokeAll, and invokeAny, and for the latter two, I do not expose timeout settings, as I am choosing to use the same ones used to construct the threadPool.  I ask the question if exposing these in my little singleton proxy wrapper class would override the timeout settings defined in the constructor above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ThreadPoolExecutor timeout is actually a keep-alive value used by it to wait that length of TimeUnit before shrinking the pool back to core size, whereas the invokeAll and invokeAny timeouts are how long to wait for the executions to occur in those methods before failing.